# Закрыть iframe после клика

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста. В чем проблема: есть айфрейм, в него подругажется сайт, на котром есть ссылки. Нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы при смене src фрейма, выкидывало из фрейма по ссылке нового src. В общем как-то рушить фрейм после действия на странице фрейма. Такое возможно?

Т.е. суть: юзер кликает по какой-то кнопке во фрейме, его начинает перекидывать на другой сайт или страницу. И нужно в этот момент фрейм разрушить, чтобы юзер новую страницу увидел в полноценном окне браузера

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Попробуйте сформулировать Ваш вопрос еще раз.

Comment: Выполнить переход из фреймаl: parent.location.href = url или ссылка с target='_parent'. Просто закрыть фрейм несколько сложней, мой вариант в комментарий не влезет.

Comment: Суть в том, что у меня нету доступа к странице которую будем фреймить. Можно ли рушить фрейм на своей стороне?

Comment: У меня точно такаяже проблема. Пробовал совет nikant25 - ничего не вышло. Толи я что-то делаю не так, толи этот метод не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.closeIframe1(); 

function closeIframe1()
{
    $(".nodeOption, .nodeOptionBlack").fadeOut(200);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Я пытался что-то выдавить, но не придумал никаких комментариев. Спасибо за подсказку.